# How to programmatically check oracle version

Tags: .net, oracle

I have a small `.NET 3.5` program which raises errors when trying to connect to an Oracle database, if it cannot access the `Oracle client DLL oci.dll` or if the `oracle DLL` version is too old. The message is:

```
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.
```

However, the exception causes the program to crash. So I would like to make the test when the program starts and gracefully terminate it if needed, with a message informing the user that he needs to `update/install/fix` the installation of `Oracle Client`. I've seen in the stack trace the method `System.Data.OracleClient.OCI.DetermineClientVersion()` but it seems not to be public. Any idea?

Comment: is this program installed using the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that routine is not public. You might hack your way around that. Otherwise this page contains some alternatives;

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1089440&tstart=15

I specifically like the one that reads the TNSPING.EXE binary and determines the ClientVersion from that ;-)